# Warning: Division by zero in ... on line 133

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

Basically, i've made a script that login to a website, get elements from the website, and divide one element with another. The problem is, i have already checked plenty of times, and the divisor is **NOT** zero. here is the snippet:

```
if($num==0)
{
    echo "<td>".$estate_income."/".$num."</td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td>".$estate_income/$num."</td>";
}
```

this would output something like `50/2000`, which means the if statement is true, which means that $num is somehow equal to 0. if i try to divide the two variables with each other, it would output `php warning diivision by zero`:

```
echo "<td>".$estate_income/$num."</td>";
```

What i ask now is, for a solution, maybe some error detection methods that could tell me what i am doing wrong. it's probably something very obvious that i have overlooked.

Thanks in advance!

*Ahmad Albayati*

#### Edit:

```
            try
            {
                echo "<td>".$estate_income/$num."</td>";
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
```

Outputs `Warning: Division by zero in . . . on line 133`

The variables i am trying to divide is within a foreach loop.

The $num variable is defined in a function that gets included:

```
function num_format($n)
{
    $n=str_replace(",","",str_replace(" ","",$n));
    if(strpos($n,".")===FALSE)
    {
        if(strpos($n,"K")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("K","000",$n));
        }
        elseif(strpos($n,"mil")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("mil","000000",$n));
        }
        elseif(strpos($n,"bil")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("bil","000000000",$n));
        }
        elseif(strpos($n,"tril")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("tril","000000000000",$n));
        }
        else
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",$n);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $n=str_replace(".","",$n);
        if(strpos($n,"K")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("K","00",$n));
        }
        elseif(strpos($n,"mil")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("mil","00000",$n));
        }
        elseif(strpos($n,"bil")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("bil","00000000",$n));
        }
        elseif(strpos($n,"tril")!==FALSE)
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",str_replace("tril","00000000000",$n));
        }
        else
        {
            $n=str_replace("$","",$n);
        }
    }
    global $num;
    $num=$n;
}
```

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @AycanYaşıt If i try to devide it, i get error

Comment: Could you just echo num in else condition too before division to make sure it's not zero or false?

Comment: no, it would give me error if i tried. when i just print $num it prints a number as it should, but it don't want to divide it

Comment: `if (intval($num) == 0)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I cannot reproduce the issue with `null` as the denominator: http://3v4l.org/prPfN

Comment: i've tried if (intval($num) == 0). the condition for the if statement was still true

Comment: `var_dump(..)` the variables.

Comment: Post the remainder of your code, especially where you define `$num`.

Comment: @GovindSingh php does not throw exceptions in such cases, using try catch blocks won't help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here.

Comment: i've updated it, you need more info? ._.

Comment: @ahmadalbayati Check what does `$num` variable contains (`var_dump($num);`) just before your `if` statement.

Comment: it output the following: string(149) "202000"

Comment: **Please stop posting random parts of a large program and post a [testcase](http://sscce.org) instead.** You should already have constructed one, to do your own debugging. It's telling that you clearly haven't.

Comment: You have `global $num;` in that function. Is it declared as global elsewhere, namely somewhere before line 133 requires it? Why doesn't num_format() return a value instead?

Comment: no, it's only declared in the function

Comment: @ahmadalbayati: Then why did you write `global $num`?

Comment: because otherwise it wouldn't output $num. i had to global the $num variable to use it outside the function. it may be wrong, but what's the correct way to do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. As I have already mentioned, I got the values from a website. When I use var_dumb on the string, it outputs `string(149) "202000"`. This actually had confused me, because the string/number was only 6 characters. so I decided to look at the source code, and I found this:

```
<spanstyle="white-space:nowrap;"><imgsrc="http: staticstorm8com="" vl="" images="" bloodpng?v="330&quot;width=&quot;9&quot;height=&quot;12&quot;style=&quot;padding-right:2px&quot;">202000<br></imgsrc="http:></spanstyle="white-space:nowrap;">
```

I got some other HTML elements in my variable when I was taking the values from the website.

Comment: There are operators and such that would permit you to scrape only the text. For instance, in Perl. (like the scripts I showed you), you can use: [^>]*>([^<]+) Which would ignore HTML, and rather grab the text itself only. (202000) in you case. lol

Comment: Lol, thanks xD . But i use strip_tags, which works perfect! thanks for the comment.